# How to determine the closure of $\mathcal{O}_A$?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, group-actions, diagonalization

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Let us consider the conjugacy action of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and let us denote $\mathcal{O}_A$ the orbit of $A$ under this action. We suppose that $\mathcal{O}_A$ is not closed in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and we want to determine $\text{cl}(\mathcal{O}_A)$.

I already proved that if $\mathcal{O}_A$ is not closed in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ hence $A$ is not diagonalizable in $\mathbb{C}$ (let us say $A \not \in \mathcal{D}_n(\mathbb{C}))$.

Hence wlog we can suppose that $A$ is for instance triangularizable on $\mathbb{C}$. Then we know that $\text{cl}(\mathcal{O}_A)$ contains a diagonalizable matrix on $\mathbb{C}$.

How could we go further ?

Thanks in advance !